# EC2 can't find documentroot folder

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2

I have an EC2 server which was setup by dev and now to download the files from my EC2 server I followed these steps

1. Logged into AWS and created an instance choosing Amazon
2. Created one PEM Key downloaded it
3. Logged into FileZilla using ec2-user and PEM Key and instance Public DNS
4. Also logged into SSH using Putty with ec2-user and then entered sudo -i to connect to root user.

I need to find my documentroot folder where my previous dev hosted the files. I can't manually find them and I also tried the following commands in SSH

`locate www` **ERROR: Bash! Command not found**
`locate html` Of course, same error :p

Then I tried
`find / -type d -name www` **Nothing returned as output**
I also tried 
`find / -type d -name html`
`find / -type f -name index.php`

But still can't find my files in documentroot. How can I find and download my source files from EC2 server?

Thanks

Comment: Did you check in the usual location, i.e. `/var/www/html`?

Comment: @DavidLevesque-Yeah, nothing found there. Also, search should show if found, that too didn't happen.

Comment: Before searching for all that,you might wanna install php5,mysql,phpmyadmin first.

Answer (score 1):

It would be great if you can post a little bit more details about your env. For example what OS? Chances are that the root directory is not even named `/var/www` or `www`

Assuming Debian/Ubuntu

- Running apache

  You can look at `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled` and see the .conf file where the document root is. For example `cat /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/mywebsite.conf`
- Running nginx

  You can look at `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled` also for the document root